# UWP: Passing data between MainPage.cs and Views\Page.cs

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a MainPage that has the code for my NavigationView. The MainPage navigates to pages with a a frame.navigate(). One of the pages contains text boxes for user entered data. I would like to take that entered data and use it to change what is displayed on another page.

I've looked at a lot of similar posts on here about passing data from one view to another, and they all use frame.navigate(typeof(page),parameter). But my parameters are not in the MainPage, where I have my navigation controls.

MainPage.xaml

```
<Page>
<Grid>
    <NavigationView x:Name="nvTopLevelNav">
        <NavigationView.MenuItems>
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Setting" Content="Page1" Tag="Page1" />
            <NavigationViewItem Icon="Rotate" Content="Page2" Tag="Page2" />
            </NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <Frame x:Name="contentFrame"></Frame>
    </NavigationView>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
namespace App
{
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
    #region NavigationView event handlers
    private void nvTopLevelNav_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {        
        // set the initial SelectedItem
        foreach (NavigationViewItemBase item in nvTopLevelNav.MenuItems)
        {
            if (item is NavigationViewItem && item.Tag.ToString()=="Page1")
            {
                nvTopLevelNav.SelectedItem = item;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    private void nvTopLevelNav_SelectionChanged(NavigationView sender, NavigationViewSelectionChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem Item = args.SelectedItem as Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem;

        if (Item.Tag is string ItemTag)
        {
            switch (ItemTag)
            {
                case "Page1":
                    contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(SettingsPage));
                    sender.Header = "Page1";
                    break;

                case "Page2":
                    contentFrame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
                    sender.Header = "Page2";
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Page1.xaml

```
<Page>
<Grid>
    <Button Name="OutputFolderButton" Click="OutputFolderButtonClick">
        <Image  x:Name="FileButton" Source="Assets/FileButton.png"/>
    </Button>
    <ToggleSwitch Name="ToggleSwitch" Toggled="SwitchToggled"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox1" TextChanged="TextBox1Changed"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox2" TextChanged="TextBox2Changed"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox3" TextChanged="TextBox3Changed"/>
    <TextBox Name="TextBox4" TextChanged="TextBox4Changed"/>
</Grid>
</Page>
```

Page1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace App
{
public sealed partial class SettingsPage : Page
{
    public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

    }
    public async void OutputFolderButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var picker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FolderPicker
        {
            SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.ComputerFolder
        };
        picker.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder outputFolder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
        if (outputFolder != null)
        {
            OutputFolderTextBox.Text = outputFolder.Path;
            OutputFolderTextBox.FontStyle = Windows.UI.Text.FontStyle.Normal;
        }
    }
    private void SwitchToggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void TextBox1Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void TextBox2Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void TextBox3Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
    private void TextBox4Changed(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
}
```

I would like the TextChanged events pass the data to the MainPage so that I can have all of the date available in one place. With all the data in the MainPage, then I can pass it to the other pages as they are called.

Comment: this is easy to pull off with mvvm and binding, it is worthy to learn this pattern if you plan to use UWP seriously.

Comment: Thank you. I'll likely use mvvm and binding for my UWP project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xeorge is right. Generally speaking, you can keep your data in a seperate data layer and each of your VM can access this data layer to get what they want. This is actually best practice for you.

And to make this more clear, please check the offcial doc: [Data binding and MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-binding/data-binding-and-mvvm)
And for more about the samples you can see this from the above doc:
"For additional guidance on using basic, out-of-the-box MVVM, check out the [Customers Orders Database sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-customers-orders-database) on GitHub. Many of the other [UWP app samples](https://github.com/Microsoft?q=windows-appsample) also use a basic MVVM architecture, and the [Traffic App sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-trafficapp) includes both code-behind and MVVM versions, with notes describing the [MVVM conversion](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-appsample-trafficapp/blob/MVVM/MVVM.md)."

Comment: Thank you Barry. This seems like the best way for me to manage my UWP project.